# efficient way of creating an event listener for multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, video, addeventlistener, fullscreen, ids

here is a scirpt using which I am enabling full-screen mode when a video is played:

```
document.getElementById("qmedia").addEventListener("playing", event => {

    const player = document.getElementById("qmedia");
    if (player.requestFullscreen) 
        player.requestFullscreen();
    else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (player.msRequestFullScreen) 
      player.msRequestFullScreen();
})
```

The challenge here is I have multiple videos on my screen and I want to avoid copy-pasting the same script multiple times.
Any suggestions for what could be an efficient method? There is also a class on my video **.qmedia**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id to class, and itarete through all the elements to add the same eventlistener to each.

```js
const players = document.querySelectorAll(".qmedia")

Array.from(players).forEach(
  player=>player.addEventListener("playing", event => {
    if (player.requestFullscreen) 
        player.requestFullscreen();
    else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (player.msRequestFullScreen) 
      player.msRequestFullScreen();
}))
```

```html
<div class="qmedia">Click</div>
<div class="qmedia">Click</div>
<div class="qmedia">Click</div>
<div class="qmedia">Click</div>
<div class="qmedia">Click</div>
```